# ASP, getting data from database

Tags: asp.net, if-statement

I'm using

```
var redirectEsetting = Esetting.FetchByRelatieId(dbConnection, (int)Context.Profile["RelatieID"]).First();
```

Now I need to check if redirectEsetting.RelatieID has a value, otherwise i'm going to use

```
    var redirectEsetting = Esetting.FetchByRelatieId(dbConnection, (int)Context.Profile["RelatieID"], true).First();
```

to get data from another place.

Yet, when I try

```
 if(redirectEsetting.RelatieID == null)
```

or something similar, it says it's an `int` and it `'can't be null'`.

Basically I need a way to check if I've got data in RelatieID

**Answer**

Easy fix:

```
if (redirectEsetting.Length < 1)
```

If no data comes, the variable will be empty, therefor just check the vars' length.

Comment: Also, I can't use .hasValue or .Value..

Comment: whats your problem now ?

Comment: @NazirUllah nothing, It's fixed. Check the question again, I've put an answer